# Exception when losing a thread

Tags: java, exception, multithreading

I start two threads with a Timer and TimerTasks

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
            TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {
                    doSomething();
                }
            };
            Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, start.getTime(),
                    1000 * 60 * 60);
```

Now sometimes the second thread stops. Is there a possibility to observe the thread perhaps for sending a mail when this thread stops, maybe by a third thread that looks for the second thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep the reference to your `Timer` alive - if the `Timer` is garbage collected, the thread will stop. From [the docs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html):

> After the last live reference to a
>   Timer object goes away and all
>   outstanding tasks have completed
>   execution, the timer's task execution
>   thread terminates gracefully (and
>   becomes subject to garbage
>   collection). However, this can take
>   arbitrarily long to occur. By default,
>   the task execution thread does not run
>   as a daemon thread, so it is capable
>   of keeping an application from
>   terminating. If a caller wants to
>   terminate a timer's task execution
>   thread rapidly, the caller should
>   invoke the timer's cancel method.

That *may* not be the problem, but it's the most likely cause. I assume if you can keep the thread alive, you don't need anything checking it?

Comment: sure =) but I want to monitor every exception and error and send an e-mail if something goes wrong with my tool =)

Comment: @Xelluloid: You could certainly add a sort of "heartbeat" in the timer thread, and then add a new thread to *check* that heartbeat every so often. It does just push the same problem one level higher though :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest adding a [**Thread#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler**](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler)) to your program.  You can have this log/email/etc..  While having a **catch(Throwable)** is better design, having an uncaught exception handler can handle any cases you miss.

Comment: but it is not an exception that is thrown but an Error :)